# import error no module named kafka

Tags: python, python-2.7, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to `import KafkaConsumer from kafka`.

It says:

> no module named kafka

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import sys

consumer = KafkaConsumer('test', bootstrap_servers='10.221.129.223')
```

> root@ubuntu-14:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1# ls bin  config  libs  LICENSE 
>   NOTICE  test.py

Any suggestions? As this was working fine sometime back. After installing latest version of kafka it throws this error.

Answer (score 12):

Hi to fix this problem you must have to install the kafka library for python: kafka-python

Here is the command for linux/debian based OS

`pip install kafka-python`

I think you also have to install kafka on your OS.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
If `Kafka` and `kafka-python` are already installed and you are still having this problem, check the python version you are running your script with. (for e.g. `kafka-python` can be installed in `python3` and you are trying to execute your script with `python2`)

Answer (score 0):

The [kafka library](https://pypi.org/project/kafka/) is now called [Kafka Python Client](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) ([official documentation](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html)).

In order to install it, if one is using Anaconda ([package page on Anaconda's official site](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/kafka-python)), one can run

```
conda install kafka-python
```

Else, one can use

```
pip install kafka-python
```

For more information on how to install it, [check this page](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/install.html).

There are other Python Clients for Kafka, such as [Confluent's Python Client](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) ([official documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/python/current/overview.html#ak-python)).

This one is also available on PyPI so one can install it using pip as follows

```
pip install confluent-kafka
```

---

**Notes**:

- If one is having issues with Python's installation, using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) might facilitate things out. If one is using Anaconda, it is recommended to use `conda install package` in the environment that one is working on, and use `pip` only if it is not available with `conda install`.
- A while back one had [pykafka](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka) but it is not maintained anymore.